# XML file to start a tcp/ip connection

Tags: xml

I am working on client server communication which is to be established using XML. I am relatively new to the programming world and don't know how to go about it. Can anyone please help on how to write and what should be the contents of the XML file. The connection is a TCP/IP one and port number can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is pure data syntax. It isn't a programming language. It isn't even a data format, by itself; it's a base for creating data formats.

So XML will not start a TCP/IP connection. However, a program which does so might read an XML file to obtain its configuration information.

You need to find or create that program.

Comment: That was indeed of a great help.
But could you please help me out with that program...??
And also what sort of data should be entered into the xml file?

Comment: "Design and write my code for me"  isn't what Stack Overflow is for. And your problem is woefully underdefined -- what kind of connection are you trying to make, what kind of data are you going to send across it, and so on. If you have a specific question, ask it. If not, go back to whoever gave you this assignment and ask them to clarify it.

Comment: Okay!!
One more thing...Can i define both the client and server data(as in the requests and responses,IP address and port no ,etc)into a single xml file or should there be two independent files for each?